# How to receive and show multiple messages in the browser with just one request?

Tags: javascript, rest, api, architecture

I'm making a web application with [**Express**](https://expressjs.com/) in [**Node.js**](https://nodejs.org) and [**SuperAgent**](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) on the client side. I have a *long process* running in the web server side that *sends a message every second* until it is done. This process is exposed as an *Rest API method* and it is started the first time it is invoked from the client side.
So, I don't know how to accomplish that, don't know if there is a way to keep the connection alive and receive multiple responses until it is finished or if I have to implement a `setInterval` method that makes a request to know the current status of that process.

Do you know what is the best way to implement this kind of functionalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right, one request receives one answer. So you either can use the setInterval to make requests in a certain time, but I would suggest that you use websockets. 
Check out [Socket.io](https://socket.io/). 
That way, you can send an update from the server, whenever the current status changes.

Answer (score 0):

Revised Version to solution
I'm gonna show you a loading screen display that changes every second, so it kinda tells you what the computer evaluates every second
Look

```html
<html>
<script>
var counter = 0;
var count = 0;
var randome = 0;
var undercount = -1; //To revert bullet behind loading bullet to original colour so that in 3 goes, the loading bar shall not be all loading colour 

console.log("Random Integer has to turn to under 5 to stop loading process");


var loadingDisplay = setInterval(myLoaderScreen, 1000);



function myLoaderScreen () {


    if (undercount > 2) {
        undercount = 0;
    }

    if (undercount < 0) {
        //Doing Nothing 
        
    }
    
    else {
        document.getElementsByClassName('Loader')[undercount].style.color = 'green'; //reverter
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    randome = Math.random() * 40;
    randome = Math.floor(randome);
    console.log("Random Integer is: "+randome);
    
    
    if (randome < 5) { //Random Integer has to turn to under 5 to stop loading process or apply limit in this if statement
        clearInterval(loadingDisplay);
    }
    
    else {
        count = counter % 3;
        document.getElementsByClassName('Loader')[count].style.color = 'blue'; //changer
        counter += 1;
        undercount += 1;
        
    }
}





</script>
<h1><span class="Load" style="color: green">Loading</span>
<span class="Loader" style="color: green">•</span>
<span class="Loader" style="color: green">•</span>
<span class="Loader" style="color: green">•</span></h1>
```

Comment: My point is to make a request to the server and receive multiple responses telling the current status of that process in execution. If that process takes 30 seconds, then, I want my javascript code to show the seconds left to the user getting the information from the server as update messages.